# how to use menu from a png file in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, photoshop

i have Two menu called menu1 and menu2 into a png file that look similar but with a different background color.
I want when hold the mouse over item1 of menu1, item1 of menu2 replace it and so on until the end.

I use the following method, but I did not receive the correct answer....

[this is my png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/228vU.jpg)

```
.img{
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background-image:url('Images/example.PNG');
background-position:-20px -30px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;}

.img:hover{
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background-image:url('Images/example.PNG');
background-position:-20px -50px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;}

        <div class="img">

        </div>
```

Comment: so your problem is currently that the full menu gets changed instead? If you want to implement such a behavior, you would need to set the same background menu for all menu items separately, and calculate the distances for each item manually as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since you want to use one image for your full menu, you will have to do your best to "size" each little image block a little.

You can define a shared sprite css class, and each single css item, and then define there mouse over counterparts, do your best to make your sprites somewhat the same size, cause at the moment they don't seem to be :)

An easier way would be to keep your menu as text, and just swap the backgrounds, as in the lower menu in the example snippet

```css
.menu-sprite {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/PeXVdXx.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
}
.menu-block {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
}
.menu1 {
  background-position: -84px -91px;
}
.menu1:hover {
  background-position: -84px -164px;
}
.menu2 {
  background-position: -154px -91px;
}
.menu2:hover {
  background-position: -154px -164px;
}
.menu3 {
  background-position: -224px -91px;
}
.menu3:hover {
  background-position: -224px -164px;
}
.menu4 {
  background-position: -294px -91px;
}
.menu4:hover {
  background-position: -294px -164px;
}
.menu5 {
  background-position: -364px -91px;
}
.menu5:hover {
  background-position: -364px -164px;
}
.menu6 {
  background-position: -434px -91px;
}
.menu6:hover {
  background-position: -434px -164px;
}
.menu7 {
  background-position: -504px -91px;
}
.menu7:hover {
  background-position: -504px -164px;
}
.menu8 {
  background-position: -574px -91px;
}
.menu8:hover {
  background-position: -574px -164px;
}
.menu9 {
  background-position: -644px -91px;
}
.menu9:hover {
  background-position: -644px -164px;
}
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.menu-item {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #efefef 0%, #efefef 75%, #dfdfdf 100%);
}
.menu-item:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ddefef 0%, #ccefef 75%, #ccdfdf 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu1"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu2"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu3"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu4"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu5"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu6"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu7"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu8"><a href="#" />
  </li>
  <li class="menu-sprite menu-block menu9"><a href="#" />
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 6</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 7</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 8</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 9</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-block"><a href="#">Item 10</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```